# xpath-puppeteer- cannot click on the element

Tags: javascript, xpath, jestjs, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

I'm trying to click on the element using xpath on puppeteer. It actually didn't throw any errors, its just that the puppeteer won't click on the element. I don't know if there's something wrong with my code.I'll be showing the element that I'm trying to click on and the 2 solutions that I made.  any help will be appreciated thanks.

this is the element that I'm trying to click on.

```
<div class="formSelectCombo-item" value="1470000113" title="Purchase Request" style="height: 15.2px; width: 100px;">Purchase Request</div>
```

first solution

```
await page.waitFor(2000); 
const prcf = await page.$x("//div[@class='formSelectCombo-item']
[@value='1470000113'][title='Purchase Request']");

 await page.waitForSelector[prcf];
 await prcf[0].click();
```

second solution

```
await page.waitFor(2000);
    const [prcf] = await page.$x("//div[@class='formSelectCombo-item'][@value='1470000113'][title='Purchase Request']");

    if (prcf)
    {
      await prcf.click();
    }
```

Comment: Try with @ before title in your XPath request. `//div[@class='formSelectCombo-item'] [@value='1470000113'][@title='Purchase Request']`

Comment: still, not clicking the element. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//div[@class='formSelectCombo-item'][@title='Purchase Request']");
await button.click();
```

Comment: still not clicking.

Comment: Hmm. Could you post the page link you are working on (or another one which looks the same) ?

Comment: I'm actually working on SAP B1 browser access application. I'm not sure if I can find one which looks the same.